# Stack 1D arrays as columns into 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, r, stack

I am trying to write code for stacking type ensemble of predictive models using R. In Python there is that `numpy.column_stack` function that stacks 1D arrays as columns into a 2D arrays. Is there a similar function in R? (I couldn't find one) or for example an "R-way" to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Could you give some more info, as in how many arrays you may want to stack into a 2D matrix structure? Also if you have tried anything yourself so far, then please share the code here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the dimensions etc. of your dataset, and/or the arrays you want to stack. That said, I would write a simple function to give me a matrix which stacks arrays as columns as below.

```
# Create dummy data of length 91
x <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
# Create dummy data of length 91
y <- seq(1, 46, 0.5)

getMat <- function(arrays, nrows, ncols, byrow = F) {
  if(length(arrays) == 0) {
    stop("The array is empty. Can't convert it to a matrix")
  }
  return (matrix(arrays, nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols, byrow = byrow))
}

# myMat will have x as first column, y as second column and so on 
myMat <- getMat(c(x, y), length(x), 2, F)
head(myMat)

# Output
head(myMat)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0  1.0
[2,]  1.1  1.5
[3,]  1.2  2.0
[4,]  1.3  2.5
[5,]  1.4  3.0
[6,]  1.5  3.5
```

I would update the answer if you could provide with more info. Also I would add one check that the length of all arrays should match before you convert or provide with some padding logic if they are of different length.

Comment: Thank you. I want to stack 4 vectors into a 2D array. My validation and testing sets are not of the same length.

Comment: @user233531 I might have mis-understood you, but so long each array you are trying to stack as columns of a matrix are of same length, this small function should do the job. for eg. -- suppose you decided to keep 700 sample size as your training set then all arrays should be of this length for converting them to matrix. And you just combine them and invoke the function. 
Else you could share some data for better understanding of all :)